# Unable to get Firebase working for Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Below I have explained my sample and have given minimal code to help understand the issue.

To my gradle file, at the end

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Inside my dependencies { } I have added

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

I also have the following in dependencies { }

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
```

Manifest I have

```
     <!-- Google Cloud Messaging -->
        <uses-permission
            android:name="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<service android:name=".support.NotificationIncoming">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".support.NotificationsIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

NotificationIncoming.java has

```
public class NotificationIncoming extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(God.LOG_TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(God.LOG_TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBookings.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

In my NotificationIDService

```
public class NotificationsIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(God.LOG_TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

On the Firebase I have done the following

1. Created a project
2. Added a SHA1 finger print
3. Downloaded the google-services.json and copied it to app folder.

I built a signed application from the same keystore as the SHA1. And ran the application. I then sent messages from Firebase console.

No luck. What am I missing ? Something really basic I think.

**EDIT**

For all those reading this, the above worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you selecting the app package name from the dropdown present on the console and BTW  `<uses-permission
            android:name="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>` is not required anymore?

Comment: Yes I have done that. For some reason a bunch of notifications were received late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any change, the above setup / code started to work, and I received these notifications late.

@shadab-ansari, yes I did add the app from the dropdown. And I have not removed the permissions from the manifest :), its working now, I am not touching it.

Comment: this seems ridiculous.. but the same problem is happening for me as well. It used to work and now without changing any configuration, keys or code, it has stopped working.. Very strange